# Geodirectory trigger open of map bubble after search

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am displaying a carousel of listings using the shortcode

```
[gd_listings post_type="gd_place" post_limit="5" add_location_filter="1" sort_by="az" title_tag="h3" layout="3" view_all_link="0" bottom_pagination="1" with_carousel="1" with_indicators="1" slide_interval="5" center_slide="1" mb="3"]enter code here
```

Instead of using the default [gd_post_title] shortcode to display the title on the listing/archive item, I have created a badge that displays the title, and when clicked it navigates to "/search/?geodir_search=1&stype=gd_place&s=%%post_title%%" essentially searching for that specific item.

After it searches, I want it to automatically trigger the map bubble to display on the map, how might I accomplish this?